# Without solving the differential equation, what can be obtained about the solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Without solving the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{3x^{2}+4x+2}{2(y-1)}, y(0)=1$, what can be obtained about the solution?

My guess is that they want me to use the local existence theorem to show that a solution exists on some interval?

Is $y'$ defined on $\mathbb{R}\times (-\infty,1)\cup \mathbb{R}\times (1,\infty)$? Because the denominator has the factor $y-1$.

If that were true, how could the condition $y(0)=1$ work? Maybe I am going the wrong direction.

Comment: Being rigorous, the only reasonable answer is that there are no solutions to the problem.

Comment: Is it because $y$ is not defined at $1$ and so the initial condition isn't satisfied?

Comment: It is because the equation itself (in this case the right-hand side) is not defined for $y=1$.